How to draw boundle box in zxing.net.maui
I got tired of searching for a way to draw a square on the border of a QR code in the zxing.net.maui library and there is no video for it. Note that the library is famous in the field of examining encrypted codes, but it is not explained in its instructions how to draw a square on the border of the codes. Has anyone implemented this topic? Please explain in detail because I am a beginner
I tried using ChatGPT but the square was drawing in the wrong place and giving wrong coordinates
update  this my code
private  void zxing_BarcodesDetected(object sender, 
BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
{
 PlayAlarm();
 zxing.IsDetecting = false;

 var first = e.Results?.FirstOrDefault();
 if (first is not null)
 {
     Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
     {
         var qrbounds = first.PointsOfInterest;

         if (qrbounds != null && qrbounds.Length > 0)
         {
             // Calculate the bounding box (coordinates might need scaling)
             double minX = qrbounds.Min(p => p.X);
             double minY = qrbounds.Min(p => p.Y);
             double maxX = qrbounds.Max(p => p.X);
             double maxY = qrbounds.Max(p => p.Y);

             // Adjust for any scaling or offset (example uses scaling factors)
             double scaleX = myAbsoluteLayout.Width / zxing.Width; // Assuming you have a cameraPreview element
             double scaleY = myAbsoluteLayout.Height / zxing.Height;

             // Apply scaling (if needed)
             minX *= scaleX;
             minY *= scaleY;
             maxX *= scaleX;
             maxY *= scaleY;

             // Create or update the bounding box frame
             var boundingBoxFrame = new Frame
             {
                 BorderColor = Colors.Green,
                 BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent,
                 WidthRequest = maxX - minX,
                 HeightRequest = maxY - minY,
                 HasShadow = true,Padding=200
             };
            
             // Position the frame within the AbsoluteLayout
             AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(boundingBoxFrame, new Rect(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY));
             AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(boundingBoxFrame, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);

             // Add or update the frame in the layout
             if (!myAbsoluteLayout.Children.Contains(boundingBoxFrame))
             {
                 myAbsoluteLayout.Children.Add(boundingBoxFrame);
             }
             for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
             {
                 await boundingBoxFrame.FadeTo(0, 100, null);
                 await boundingBoxFrame.FadeTo(60, 100, null);
             }
             boundingBoxFrame.IsVisible = false;
         }
         if (first.Format == ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeFormat.QrCode)
         {
             GetResults(first.Value);
         }
     });
 }

}

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
